# как поменять цвет фона и штрихов в python (python-barcode можно использовать и другую библиотеку) вместо pillow можно использовать другую библиотеку

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, barcode

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
def barcodegen(text, encoding):
    encoding = barcode.get_barcode_class(str(encoding))
    img = encoding(str(text), writer = ImageWriter())
    img.save('barcodes/barcode')
```

это работает, но только с белым цветом, а штрих код должен иметь жёлтый цвет фона, и зелёные штрихи сейчас сам штрих-код выглядит так причём цвет должен вызываться тоже в функции:

(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/759686669192003594/759753874923061288/barcode.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Нужно задать опции `save`
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

#from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
def barcodegen(text, encoding):
    encoding = barcode.get_barcode_class(str(encoding))
    img = encoding(str(text), writer=ImageWriter())
    img.save('barcodes/barcode', options={"background": "gold","foreground": "green"})
```

Comment: спасибо, работает